How to change the default text "Add an existing work item as a parent" of linkControlOption in Azure DevOps work item form using process XML?
I am customizing a work item form in Azure DevOps using process XML, and I want to change the default text that appears in a link control (text that appiers below add link button):

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I modified the properties of the  element, such as EmptyText, Label etc, but it didn’t seem to have any effect.
I reviewed the available properties for , but I couldn’t find anything related to default text.
Here is the xml what i am using
<Group Label="Evidence">
     <Control Type="LinksControl" Name="Evidence">
          <LinksControlOptions>
               <LinkFilters>
                    <WorkItemLinkFilter Type="System.LinkTypes.Related" />
               </LinkFilters>
               <Columns>
                    <Column Name="System.WorkItemType" />
                    <Column Name="System.State" />
               </Columns>
               <WorkItemTypeFilters>
                    <Filter WorkItemType="Evidence" />
               </WorkItemTypeFilters>
           </LinksControlOptions>
     </Control>
</Group>

I’m using Azure DevOps Server 2022, and I’m unsure if this level of customization is supported.

Is it possible to customize the default/placeholder text for LinksControl or other controls using process XML?
If so, which property or configuration should I use?

Any guidance or alternative approaches would be appreciated.

LinksControlOptions does not include such properties.
